# REST. Comparing two JSON representations

Tags: json, rest, hal-json

I have a tag system:

#### Tag

- id
- name
- children tags

so they could be nested (max depth 3)

for example:

- Food

  - Restaurant
  - Fast food
  - Chinese food
- Medicine

  - Hospitals
  - Pharmacy
- Entertainment

  - Extreme

    - Skiing
    - Skating
  - Family

And I have some resources that have tags.

#### Place

- id
- name
- tags

And I have few endpoints:

`/api/tags`

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "/api/tags/1"
        }
      },
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Food",
      "_embedded": {
        "children": [
          {
            "_links": {
              "self": {
                "href": "/api/tags/4"
              }
            },
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Restaurant",
            "_embedded": {
              "children": []
            }
          },
          {
            "_links": {
              "self": {
                "href": "/api/tags/5"
              }
            },
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Fast food",
            "_embedded": {
              "children": []
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "/api/tags/2"
        }
      },
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Medicine",
      "_embedded": {
        "children": []
      }
    },
    {
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "/api/tags/3"
        }
      },
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Entertainment",
      "_embedded": {
        "children": []
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And `/api/place/1`

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "FooBar Arena",
  "_embedded": {
    "tags": [
      {
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "/api/tags/1"
          }
        },
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Food"
      },
      {
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "/api/tags/2"
          }
        },
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Medicine"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So I don't want tags to have embedded resources when they are listed as embedded resources themselves, but by NOT including embedded children I ended up with two different  representations of the same data with the same SELF link, how clients should compare those? Comparing SELF links would work but one representation lacks `children`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe a good HAL client does *not* consider `_embedded` to be part of the representation. A good HAL client simply uses the values from `_embedded` to warm a cache. Items that appear in `_embedded` should still appear in `_links`.

So as long as the tags appear in `_links` for every resource, there should be no need to embed the same resource more than once.

Comment: Makes sense. Didn't finished reading spec https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-kelly-json-hal-08#section-8.3.